# ngrok FTP tunneling issue

Tags: ftp, filezilla, tunneling, ngrok

I have installed many FTP Servers on a Windows machine and set ngrok for FTP tunneling.

```
C:\path\to\ngrok> ngrok tcp 21
```

Using linux, i am able to establish an FTP connection and browse the directories ONLY with the installed ftp client.

```
$ ftp 
ftp> open 0.tcp.ngrok.io port_here
```

The problem is that FileZilla, Classic FTP File Transfer Software, Chrome & Firefox extensions, failed.

FileZilla output:

```
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I wonder why i can't browse using FileZilla, but with the ftp Linux command works well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved in FileZilla via :

Edit > Settings > Connection > FTP > Passive mode, and select "Fall back to active mode" and Bingo !

The same technique can be applied to the other FTP clients.